# getting device not paired after pairing in my Bluetooth app

Tags: android, bluetooth

> i am building an app to display the Ecg in mobile .so i try to
>   establish a connection via bluetooth .but when i try to pair the
>   Bluetooth, the paired devices are shown. but when i try to connect, it
>   says device not found..i don't know how to solve the problem. Please
>   advise on issues in my code to connect to paired devices:Any help on
>   this would be greatly appreciate
>
> this is my bluetooth.java

```
public class bluetooth extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static void  disconnect(){
        if (connectedThread !=null){
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread= null;
        }
    }

    public static void gethandler(Handler handler){

        mHandler= handler;
    }

    static  Handler mHandler =new Handler();

    static ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    public static final UUID my_UUID= UUID.fromString("f53a07d4-3010-11e9-b210-d663bd873d93");

protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT=0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ=1;
ListView listView;
//ArrayAdapter is an Android SDK class for adapting an array of objects as a datasource.
// Adapters are used by Android to treat a result set uniformly whether it's from a database, file, or in-memory objects
// so that it can be displayed in a UI element.
// The ArrayAdapter is useful for the latter. Use it anywhere you would use an Adapter. E.g. attach to Android UI elements.
ArrayAdapter<String> list_adapter;
static BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;

///ArrayList is an implementation of java.util.List that's backed by an array. You can use it anywhere you would use a java.util.List.
//// E.g. where you need to maintain order of a collection of objects where duplicates are allowed.
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devies;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //in Android the visual design is created in xml . And each Activity is associated to a design
        //
        //setContentView(R.layout.main)
        //R means Resource
        //
        //layout means design
        //
        //main is the xml you have created under res->layout->main.xml
        //
        //Whenever you want to change your current Look of an Activity or when you move from
        // one Activity to another . The other Activity must have a design to show . So we call this method in onCreate
        // and this is the second statement to set the design
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
       init();
if(btAdapter==null){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no bt detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: no");
    finish();
}
else{
    if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
        turnOnBT();
    }
    getPairedDevices();
    startDiscovery();
}
    }

private void  getPairedDevices(){
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}

    private void  turnOnBT(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }

    private void  startDiscovery(){
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
        pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
            String s="";
            list_adapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+""+"\n"+device.getAddress());

            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
    listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     list_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
     listView.setAdapter(list_adapter);
     btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     pairedDevices =new ArrayList<String>();
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
     devies = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
     receiver =new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             String action =intent.getAction();
             if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 devies.add(device); //!!!!!!!!!!
                 String s="";
                 for (int a=0;a<pairedDevices.size();a++){
                     if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                         s="(paired)";
                         break;
                     }
                 }
               list_adapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+""+"\n"+device.getAddress());

             }
             else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){

             }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){

             }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                 if(btAdapter.getState()==btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                     turnOnBT();
                 }
         }
     }



     };

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(list_adapter.getItem(position).contains("(paired)")){
            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devies.get(position);
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device not paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private  final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice=device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discover y because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                //connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    // Incoming and the outgoing strings are carried out inside this thread read is for reading incoming messages through a socket and write is for sending messages to the remote device
    static class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // socket not created
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        StringBuffer sbb = new StringBuffer();
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer ;
            int bytes;
            // receiving message
          while(true) {
              try {
                  try {
                      sleep(30);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      break;
                  }

                  buffer = new byte[1024];
                  // Read from the InputStream
                  bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                  // message is in bytes form so reading them to obtain message

                  mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // connection was lost and start your connection again
                  Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                  break;
              }
          }
        }

        public void write(String income) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(income.getBytes());
                for (int i=0;i<income.getBytes().length;i++)
                    Log.v("outStream"+Integer.toString(i),Character.toString((char)(Integer.parseInt(Byte.toString(income.getBytes()[i])))));
                try{
                Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
            public void cancel(){
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }
}
```

> but my question is, are there any problem with mmsocket

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SPBp.png)

i geeting like beow in my android phone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bumik.jpg)

Comment: Try this lib : https://github.com/Manikandan92/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary

Comment: please somebody help me.

Comment: It's maybe connection logic has been wrong. Could you check it and try it

Comment: Sorry i can't understand.Could  you please explain clearly. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth or BLE???

Comment: i am using bluetooth. because  i am developing this app for ECG and i am using hc-05 bluetooth module